# Software to capture data from a Kinect

Tags: video, kinect

I'm looking for a piece of software that captures the raw data from a Microsoft Kinect, that is both the VGA RGB image and the depth map.

Simple question, I'm hoping there is a simple answer.

Comment: which version of kinect are you using and what sdk ? short answer: try Kinect Studio to record the streams if you're using the microsoft sdk

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, if you're developing for the *Kinect*, you probably downloaded the *SDK* from Microsoft Website. You can then use the *Kinect Studio* as described in [Microsoft Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh855395.aspx).

The problem is that the file is saved in *.xes* file. And i'm assuming you probably want them as another kind of video file. Apparently there is no simple solution to this issue as seen in a question made in [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3d821fcf-4602-44d6-bfb4-4dbd1b89d58d/about-the-recorded-file-by-kinect-studioxed-file-how-can-i-get-the-recorded-datargb-image-or?forum=kinectsdk). I think the more not simple, but certainly possible way to do it would be using developing an application that reads the *RGB/Depth* image buffer from the *Kinect* and convert them to a video file.

A good start to do so would be using the examples in the *SDK* browser and build upon them. I'm assuming you're using *Kinect v2.x*.